# Continuity of two variables in toplogical space .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, metrizability

Let $T$ is subset of real numbers .Let  $k$ is any number which is not in $T$ .

Define   $$kT =\{ kt   : t \in T\}. $$ 
Let $W$ is toplogy(not usual) on $T$ , then  can you prove that :

$$H=\{ kU :  U \in W \}$$  is topology for $kT$ .

And is the function $f:kT\times kT\to kT$  continuous with respect to $H$  if it is defined as 
 $$f (kt,ks)=k (t+s ),$$    for  $t ,s \in  T$?

Note that it is given : for every $s,t \in T $, $s+t$ belongs to $T .$

Comment: The second line is unclear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy can you  explain it little more. How by definition  it will hold?

Comment: @Guru I had misread the second part. I have posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Thew first part follows from the relations $k(\cup U_i)=\cup kU_i$, $k(U \cap V)=kU\cap kV$, $k\emptyset =k\emptyset$. For the second part, taking $T=(1,\infty)$ and $k=1$ you are asking if $(t,s) \to t+s$ is continuous for ANY topology on $(1,\infty)$.  This is not true.

Comment: Kavi Rama murthy thanks for your reply .But i am asking how can we check continuity of above function with respect to topology  H? Not on arbitrary toplogy .Thanks onece again.

Comment: @Guru When $k=1$  $kT=T$ and the topology on $kT$ is same as the topology on $T$. The topology yon $T$ is not specified. It can be any topology. So the map $(t,s) \to t+s$ need not be continuous.

Comment: Ok... thanks a lot sir ,  kavi Rama murthy .one last qeustion   " which book is the  best to understand the concept of " toplogical fields " , homeomorphism between toplogical fields and  homeomorphism on field structure together with isomorphisim  for beggner"?